# QODBC error 80004005 when trying to run .vbs file to update info in QB

Tags: vb6, odbc, 32bit-64bit, quickbooks

I have set up the QODBC driver and was able to connect to my QB file and run queries in the VB Demo 32.

I am looking at one of the Sample Files, found here - http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/506/57/examples-of-how-to-use-qodbc-via-visual-basic

I did what this article said - copied all of the text into a text file, saved it as "Customer.vbs". I created a Customer named "Kim Garland", closed the dialogue box, double clicked on the file. The msgbox never displayed, and this error message came up - "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application; Code: 80004005; Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers"

Any idea what is going on here? After looking through the knowledge base, I thought it might have something to do with 64-bit vs 32-bit... but that didn't seem to get me anywhere. I do have Visual Studio installed, but don't quite know enough about VB6 apps to know what I'm doing.

**EDIT**
By the way, the line that is giving the error is:

```
oConnection.Open "DSN=Ben Test 2;OLE DB Services=-2"
```

I originally was using the same exact line that was in the article that I linked to, but that was not working either. I used the c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe to create a 32-bit DSN called "Ben Test 2". It didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the Microsoft's website where they talk about it.
It is not VB issue, it is 32/64bit issue as you suspect.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlgetstarted/thread/702f0d9b-6cb9-49cf-9953-80d059711e60

Comment: Thanks. Your confirmation that it was a 32 bit vs 64 bit issue inspired me to try one more thing, so I'll go ahead and accept your answer. I actually fixed it by using Qremote, which is a bridge between 64-bit apps and the 32 bit driver. If anyone wants help with this issue, I'd be glad to walk you through it. Just contact me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using 64-bit system, your VBS  will be execute as 64-bit (by default).

QODBC is 32-bit driver, and can work with 32-bit applications. A 64-bit applications cannot talk to a 32 bit Driver and same is with 64bit application to 32 bit Driver.

For 64-bit applications use QRemote (which is a 64-bit Driver driver).

Solution 1
You can try to use QRemote to bridge QODBC and your application. Here is an article about how to use QRemote:
http://www.qodbc.com/qremoteconnect.htm

Solution 2
and there is another solution for you issue. Please call your VBS as 32 bit. Please follow the steps below:

1) Click Windows Start

2) Click Run, in the window, type "%windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe"

3) Click OK, then type "cscript vbscriptfile.vbs" in the cmd window

This will make your VBS run in 32-bit mode even thou you are in 64-bit machine

-Regards
Rajendra Dewani

Comment: interesting... this is the exact same answer that the QODBC support gave me. Literally. By the way, I was able to make both of these solutions work. If you are calling this from an Excel macro instead, use the 32 bit one.